# Singleton That is Nowhere Dense

Tags: general-topology

> Is it true that every one-point subset must be nowhere dense in $(X,d)$?

I'm attempting to answer this but when I think of Euclidean space, this seems to be true. What am I missing?

Comment: Is $(X,d) $ arbitrary, or a subset of some Euclidean space?

Comment: Arbitrary. Euclidean space is just my go to for examples/counter-examples.   @AndrésE.Caicedo

Comment: Consider a one-point metric space.  Is that point nowhere dense?

Comment: @GEdgar No, because $cl({x})= {x}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your question stands it is false, what GEdgar is trying to point out. 
Being nowhere dense is dependent in what ambient space you are working. As GEdgar also states, a space is always dense in itself so if your metric space is $(X=\{x\},d)$ then $\{x\}$ is dense in itself.

Similarly, if you consider $\mathbb{Z}$ equipped with the discrete topology singletons are not nowhere dense as every singleton is an open set and hence is dense in itself.

However, as you noted if the ambient space is the standard euclidean space singletons are nowhere dense.

To wrap this up, the important thing is what ambient space you are working in and what topology you are considering. Hope this helps.